# Java error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, spring, mule, classnotfoundexception

Let me preface this by saying I'm not a Java developer, but rather a Python developer who needs to leverage a small portion of Java code for a project. :-)

That being said, I'm receiving the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CustomSecurePropertyPlaceholderModule
```

using the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<domain:mule-domain xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
                    xmlns:domain="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/domain"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
                    xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
                    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                    xmlns:tls="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls"
                    xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
                    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
                    xmlns:secure-property-placeholder="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/secure-property-placeholder"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
                                        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
                                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
                                        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/domain http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/domain/current/mule-domain-ee.xsd
                                        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
                                        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls/current/mule-tls.xsd
                                        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/secure-property-placeholder http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/secure-property-placeholder/current/mule-secure-property-placeholder.xsd
                                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="secure-property-placeholder" class="CustomSecurePropertyPlaceholderModule">
            <spring:property name="encryptionAlgorithm" value="AES" />
            <spring:property name="encryptionMode" value="CBC" />
            <spring:property name="keyFilePath" value="keyfile.properties" />
            <spring:property name="locations" value="secure.properties"/>
            <spring:property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
            <spring:property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>


</domain:mule-domain>
```

I've ensured `src/main/java` is on the build path within the run config (the file `CustomSecurePropertyPlaceholderModule` resides there). I also see that `shared_resources/target/classes` is set as the output folder in the run config as well. Any ideas why I'm still receiving this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, classes are usually in packages.

Like, `com.yourself.CustomSecurePropertyPlaceholderModule`

Try putting your class (I hope you have it) into `src/main/java/com/yourself`, prepend with `package com.yourself`; and use

```
<spring:bean id="secure-property-placeholder" class="com.yourself.CustomSecurePropertyPlaceholderModule">
```

Comment: Thanks @alamar for the assistance! I just created the new package, moved the class to the package, updated the reference within the class, as well as the spring bean. Still receiving the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: @PaulCalabro can you please provide the whole stack trace (more the better)? There could be non-trivial information there.

Comment: Sure thing! Here's a gist that contains the information: https://gist.github.com/paulcalabro/b8c6a46041b8b555879f52d1583daf58

(it was too long to post)

Comment: @PaulCalabro what's `org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader`? I guess it's what causes class loading troubles.

Comment: Oh interesting! Given the name, it definitely sounds relevant. It's a class provided by Mule ESB. That's all I really know. I'm using that product to do some automation (most of the code is in Python). I just resolved this issue by instead using an environmental variable, but I'll accept your answer as it looks like you've isolated the most likely culprit. Thanks for your assistance!